# Visa options for working remotely for US in France as an American software engineer married to French citizen

Tags: visa, working-visas, france

My wife is French and has recently moved back to Paris for a new job. I am a US citizen software engineer and have been working for my current company (financial firm) for 4.5 years and they are open to me working from France remotely. They do not have a presence in France and I dont think it is an option to create one.

I have come across a lot of varying information regarding visas/taxation/etc and have a number of questions:

1. If I get the spouse visa, are there stipulations that I must work for for domestic French companies only?
2. I have heard of people getting the 1 year stay visa and working for US companies and renewing each year. Does this require me to pay taxes in the USA? France? Both? And are there any legal/compliance issues for my company given they do not have a legal presence there?
3. Can I go the independent contractor route on a spouse visa, or is that something different?

With the 1 year visa, I would assume I would need to get private insurance if I don't pay taxes in France.

Comment: Which visa or residence permit you get does not impact whether you must pay taxes in France (and I am only posting a comment because I don't have a definitive answer to that question). As far as immigration is concerned, the spouse visa is the most logical choice, it's easier and gives you a stronger legal position but it does not solve the tax/insurance/contract issues. Only drawback is what would happen in case you and your wife separate in the first few years of your stay (after that, you will get a long-term residence permit and have other options, including becoming a French citizen).

Comment: Note that going the contractor route could be delicate, not from a visa/immigration perspective but from a work/social security perspective. You cannot legally choose to be a contractor if you are effectively working like an employee. That's true even for French citizens and is totally unrelated to your right to live and work in France.